# When creating lists, it seems that forms like [[False] * 3] * 3 only copies the references?

Tags: python, list

I create a list using the below codes.

```py
a = [[False] * 3] * 3
```

which creates a 3x3 matrix with all elements of `False` value.

And when I changed `a[0][0]` to be `True` using `a[0][0] = True`, the result is:

```py
[[True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, False]]
```

where the entire first column changes into `True`.

However, if I create `a` using the `for` loop, like:

```py
a = [[False] * 3 for i in range(3)]
```

or

```py
a = [[False for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
```

And after executing the same `a[0][0] = True`, I get my desired result in both ways as:

```py
[[True, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

where just one element is changed into `True`.

Why there is such difference in creating the list in Python? Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `[False] * 3` gives us a list of 3 references of the same `False`, but since boolean is immutable, each one of those is independent.
- `[[False] * 3] * 3` gives us a list of 3 references of the same `[False] * 3`, and since list is mutable, those 3 lists are actually the same.
- `a = [[False] * 3 for i in range(3)]` is equivalent to:

```py
a = []
for i in range(3):
    a.append([False] * 3)
```

That should tells you why the lists are different.

- For `[[False for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)]`, the only difference from above is that the `False`s are created independently, but since boolean is immutable anyway, the result is identical to the above.

Comment: "3 copies of" is inaccurate. It's the same object 3 times - or in other words, 3 references to the same object. This is true regardless of whether the object is mutable.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That's true, let me edit my answer.